# Notepad++, see what a saved run command does

Tags: notepad++

I know how to run a command automatically using "Run->Run", or F5. I know how to save the command with a shortcut as well. My question is, given that I have saved a command with a short cut, and that it now appears in my "Run" menu, and that I've forgotten what I put in it as the command to run, how do I check what it was? If I use "Run -> Modify Shortcut/Delete Command...", it seems that I can only change the shortcut, but can't check what the command was in the first place.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

All shortcuts are saved in a file called `shortcuts.xml` and in there you can see what they do.

Depending on your version of Windows this file can be located in different places.

- `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\shortcuts.xml`
- `C:\Documents and Settings\[username]\Application Data\Notepad++\shortcuts.xml`

Using env variables:

```
%appdata%\Notepad++\shortcuts.xml
```

Comment: Sadly the file can't be edited by hand as it gets overwritten on exit. Command tweaks require the command be deleted and re-added.